# Subscribe to an audience with Parse Dashboard

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, push-notification, back4app

I'm having trouble subscribing to an audience from my iOS app for Push Notifications. I've created several Audiences from the dashboard on Back4App. But I don't know how to subscribe or unsubscribe from my app in Xcode.

My problem is that **whether they're subscribed or not; the device is *always* getting the notification**

This is how I'm subscribing:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"General" forKey:@"channels"];
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"Events" forKey:@"channels"];

[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

And unsubscribing:

```
[currentInstallation removeObject:announcementTitles[indexPath.row] forKey:@"channels"];
```

But whichever way, when I send a notification to a specific audience from the dashboard, it sends to everyone.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add a print screen of the audience you are trying to send to and everybody is receiving? Channel is different from audience. Your code is correctly adding a channel to a installation. Now you have to create an audience that filters for this specific installation and then send to this audience.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I sent and email to the Back4app team, and they told me the Audience feature on the dashboard is broken currently. However, I was able to successfully send notifications to specific channels through my app instead of through the dashboard.

Comment: It should be working now. In the case you try again and it still not working, let me know.